# How to link a cell to sheet reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I type `Sheet2!E8` in `A1` Cell of Sheet1, it will show the value of E8 cell of Sheet2. But I want to use this reference link from a cell in Sheet1

[image]

Please, look at the snapshot. I want to use the `C1` cell to get the `Sheet2` part of `Sheet2!E8`. So If I change the value of `C1` from `Sheet2` to `Sheet3`, then the formula in `A1` will be changed to `Sheet3!E8`. Also If I extend the formula from A1 to A2, `E8` should have to be `E9` automatically (increment).

How to achieve this?

Comment: The question wording still reflected the original example.  I fixed that and updated the answer to be consistent with the current question wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the INDIRECT function to build a cell reference from strings and formulas like what you want to do:

```
=INDIRECT($C$1&"!E"&ROW()+7)
```

The ampersand concatenates the pieces of the string.  The `!E` portion is a literal value you want to incorporate, so that goes in quotes.  `$C$1` is not in quotes, so that gets replaced by C1's contents.  `ROW()+7` returns the `8` value in cell A1, and will increment as you copy it down the column.  INDIRECT then converts the resulting string into a cell reference and the formula returns the value in `sheet2!E8`.

Note that you can incorporate formulas, etc. when you build the string.  The resulting string just needs to be a cell reference.

Comment: Thanks fixer1234 for your quick reply. Your formula worked well, but I also want to auto increment A3 of this formula if I extend this formula to next row. In this formula this A3 is static in case of extending the formula.

Comment: That's where the ability to incorporate formulas comes in handy.  You could do something like: `=INDIRECT(C1&"!A"&ROW()+2)`.  In cell A1, `ROW()+2` would equate to `3`, and the value would increment for subsequent rows.  If that's not the exact situation, at least it will illustrate how to approach it.

Comment: fixer1234, thanks but it will not do exactly what I want to do. Suppose, If It has to be `Sheet2!E8`, then how row()+2 will calculate it?

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid, your question only describes using the sheet2 reference.  Translating A3 is a logical extension.  BTW, I should have anchored the C1 reference like this: `=INDIRECT($C$1&"!A"&ROW()+2)` so that cell reference doesn't change when you copy the formula to other cells.  Sheet2!E8 doesn't directly follow from the question (where would you be on sheet1 when you refer to that cell?).  It sounds like there's more complexity to what you want to do than is described in the question.  Can you edit the question to explain the full range of what you need to do?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please review it. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: fixer1234, I have one more problem with this formula although your solution is okay for this topic (and I have accepted your answer and upvoted it). Please look at my new problem and please give me a solution. Here is the link http://superuser.com/questions/1150829/how-to-reference-worksheet-with-name-space